CORS error while fetching image from Firestore
I am facing CORS error whenever I try to access the image from localhost:5000. This is the error I am facing.

app.html:1 Access to image at 'https://example.io/icons/AWS/Res_Amazon-Redshift_Dense-Compute-Node_48.svg' from origin 'http://localhost:5000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I have added cors.json like this
[
  {
    "origin": ["localhost:5000"],
    "method": ["GET"],
    "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
  }
]

After that I have run the below command, but I am still facing this CORS error
gsutil cors set cors.json gs://[projectId].appspot.com 


I believe the origin should include the http://

The origin has to match exactly, inclusive protocol, ie it should be http://localhost:5000

I have tested with that also and with "*" but it is not working.

The url you are trying to access mentions AWS, yet you are configuring CORS for a google cloud storage? Are you sure "https://example.io/icons/AWS/"  is really pointing to that google cloud storage?

Yes they are stored in my Firestore database, Actually I have categorized the icons based on the service provider like Google, Aws etc.

What does gsutil cors get gs://[projectId].appspot.com  give you? If that gives you a valid CORS configuration, the only explanation is, that https://example.io/ is not pointing to the bucket gs://[projectId].appspot.com

It gives me this response [{"maxAgeSeconds": 3600, "method": ["GET"], "origin": ["http://localhost:5000"]}].

well, your origin is wrong. It should be http://localhost:5000

Actually it is http://localhost:5000 but when I paste this on stackoverflow then automatically removes the http://

And yes of course you can open this link in the browser if you just click on in or paste it in the address bar, because that's not a CORS request ...
